# How to Query salesforce recycle bin usin api?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to query the recycle bin object with web API. I need to fetch the rows deleted in SalesForce Object so is there any other object that provides the history of deleted rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by "web API". You're connecting to Salesforce from some other app using SOAP API? Have a look at `getUpdated` & [`getDeleted`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm) calls (link contains details & sample code).

With REST API you can achieve similar results: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm

So now you should have some keywords too search for :)
Just remember that not all objects end up in Recycle Bin. Some are hard deleted. Check answers to this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24282/which-objects-do-not-go-to-the-recycle-bin-upon-deletion

Comment: I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce library to fetch the data of salesforce object. I simply provide the SOQL query and it fetch the data. Can you have a look at it and give me some idea, Is your above answer and this library can fit ?

Comment: It's right there on the page you linked to, look for `sf.Contact.deleted` example

Comment: Oh god. it was right there and I looked everywhere except there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select deleted records which are placed in Recycle Bin, you need just add query condition for checking records with 'isDeleted' field equals true.
For instance in SOQL you can get deleted accounts with such query:

```
accounts = [select id from Account where isDeleted = true ALL ROWS];
```

If you use SOAP API you can check out [getDeleted() method documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm).

Comment: I tried running this query at https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php . It shows the malformed query error. If I delete a row it it completely deleted from table too.

Comment: "ALL ROWS" works only in Apex code. API access (including Workbench query editor) has to use`queryAll` or similar name instead of `query`. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199524&type=1. For example in SOAP API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm

Comment: @eyescream, thanks for your comment, you are certainly right.