# Salesforce get all objects that changed after some date

Tags: salesforce

I would like to keep an updated copy of some salesforce data in a database.

e.g. a table with all contacts

However, it is impractical to truncate the table and to query all data again on a frequent basis.

Is there some way to only query changed contacts since the last sync?

e.g. I would run an hourly job that gets all contacts that changed within the last hour.

In addition, how could I deal with deleted contacts. I assume that if there is a way to get changed ones this might not include deletions.

Comment: most tables will let you do "WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2022-05-19T12:00:00Z" but your first choice should be "data replication api". I'm not saying it's a duplicate but  (shameless plug) have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/69918225/313628 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/46706347/313628 ?

Answer (score 0):

To query all contacts modified since a particular date/time:

```
Datetime OneHourAgo = System.now().addHours(-1); 
List<Contact> AllContactsModfiedSinceDateTimeX = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SystemModStamp >= : OneHourAgo];
```

Same query but including all deleted contacts:

```
Datetime OneHourAgo = System.now().addHours(-1); 
List<Contact> AllDeletedContactsModfiedSinceDateTimeX = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SystemModStamp >= : OneHourAgo AND isDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS]; //"ALL ROWS" must be included when using isDeleted = TRUE
```